# Notebook won't use dedicated graphic card

Tags: windows, windows-10, graphics-card

I have a Dell XPS 15 and I recently re-installed Win 10 (I don't know if the same behavior was happening before that).

I have also installed the Geforce Experience and the graphic card driver using this application.

I'm realizing that almost always the gpu usage is handled by the Intel graphics and not the NVidia Geforce as you can see in the image below.

[image]

My question is, wouldn't it be more performant if Windows used the dedicated one? And if so, how can I fix it?

Comment: The idea is that the low-power GPU is used for simple 2D work. The heavy lifting is done for 3D, games etc, which should switch automatically to the NVidia.

Comment: It *might* perform faster, but it would use significantly more power. The question for you is does it *ever* use the Nvidia GPU or is it "stuck" on the Intel one?

Comment: use Geforce driver settings to use dedicated card for games. In Win10 v1803 you can also [configure this in Windows settings](https://winblogs.azureedge.net/win/2018/02/d7ce934824f7922ff5a22965bbf68c5b.png)

Comment: @Mokubai, I'm not a gamer so I wasn't worried about it, but I installed a game and tried and dedicated card was used for that. I just thought that it would also be used for viewing videos such as youtube.

Comment: @VinTem The integrated graphics chip will have a hardware video decoder the same as your dedicated card and so it will be lower power for it to use the integrated graphics for anything other than dedicated 3D applications such as games. Sounds like your system is working as intended.